# Dealing with functions without a root, when using the Newton method

Tags: equation-solving

In this thread, with the help of different members, I was able to understand how to implement my code as a function, that one can call for whatever function : [Newton Method of finding roots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278174/newton-method-of-finding-roots?noredirect=1#comment694591_278174)

Then i realised that, it can happen that a function might not have a root i.e: x^2 +1.
When trying the code for this function one gets as the final value (after 20 iterrations): -2.27226. Now if you use this as your input in the function, the end result is bigger then 1 and at least bigger then 0.1

So i thought of using a boundary value so that, for function values larger then this one, we can say with certainty that the function has no root. So I did the following modification on the code:

```
> newtonRoots[f_, x_Symbol, x0_?NumericQ,(nIterations_Integer)?Positive]
> := Module[{p, data, n},    p[0] = x0;    vk=Table[p[n + 1] = N[p[n] -
> f[p[n]]/f'[x] /. x -> p[n]]; {n, p[n]}, {n, 0,nIterations}]
>        If[f[vk[[nIterations]]]>=0.1,Stringform["The function has no roots"],Stringform["The function has a root"]]    ];
```

But when I tried it,  I got as a result something, that can be explained as a visual glitch. I cannot copy it here. Is it wrong to use a value, for which, if the function has a way smaller value then it, then one can say with certainty that a root exist, and no if otherwise

Comment: Assuming I've understood this correctly, your `vk` is a list of pairs. So, your condition looks like this: `{567, 0.} >= 0.1`. That is considered an indeterminate form for Equal, GreaterEqual, etc. You could try using this condition: `f[vk[[nIterations, -1]]] >= 0.1`.

Comment: or probably just `f[vk[[-1, -1]]] >= 0.1`.

Comment: But would this be a good condition for whether the root exist or no? + lericr If you have 5 min time, could we go in a chat room?

Comment: happy to chat if you want

Comment: How do I open a chatroom xD?

Comment: good question. :)

Comment: hmm, I tried to create a chat room, but couldn't seem to add you.

Comment: maybe me more comments lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141789/discussion-between-imbaf-and-lericr).